# Passing day, month and year to my macro

Tags: macros, datetime

I just wanted to ask, how to do something like this - I have my own macro, that needs custom date passed as arguments:

```
\newcommand{\introduction}[3]{
This is regarding your loan application that was on \formatdate{#1}{#2}{#3}.}
```

And then I use this macro in the text with custom day, month and year. But LaTeX shows me current date. So, what is wrong? Is it because the date isn't known in the preambule (and current date is used as default)?
Thank you for your hints.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you are using this macro, but for me it produces the date that I specify in the parameters to the macro:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newcommand{\introduction}[3]{%
This is regarding your loan application that was on \formatdate{#1}{#2}{#3}.}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\introduction{04}{05}{1977}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just created another file and it works. So, the mistake have to be in another place. I guess this could be the problem:
`\newdateformat{todaydate}{% 
\ordinal{DAY} \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\todaydate`